# Plugin Theme CSS

Tags: plugins, css

For a Plugin Theme, I have been unable to include some changes, and have to change them in the plugin itself:

`/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/assets/css/`

```
.myplugin #content div.product div.images,
.myplugin div.product div.images,
.myplugin -page #content div.product div.images,
.myplugin -page div.product div.images{
    width:40%;
}
```

But when I put this style in the theme `style.css`, the required width do not get rendered.

How should I fix the theme for raising the priority of this css?

Comment: where are you putting these styles?  The admin customizer?

Comment: Your CSS needs to be more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the original to take precedence.

Answer (score 2):

You would be better off creating a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/), this will ensure your edits do not get wiped out when you update Woo.

Anyway, this CSS should work.  I usually avoid using `!important` but without seeing your page it's hard to say what is overriding your styles.

```
.woocommerce #content div.product div.images,
.woocommerce div.product div.images,
.woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images,
.woocommerce-page div.product div.images{
    width:40% !important;
}
```

Comment: You know that WooCommerce is off-topic here (as are other third-party plugins), right?